# typeahead.js calls the wrong remote URL

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, typeahead.js

I am trying to get Typeahead.js 0.9.3 to work with jQuery 1.9.1 but to no avail.

When entering a value into `#myinput`, Typeahead does fire an ajax call. But instead of calling the specified remote url, Typeahead calls the url of the current page.

Here is my configuration (real values replaced):

```
$('#myinput').typeahead({
  name: 'names',
  remote: '/myapp.cgi?q=%QUERY'
});
```

There are no errors logged to the Chrome console when the page is loading.

Best regards,
Martin

Comment: Do you have anything else acting on `$('#myinput')`?

Answer (score 1):

After a few hours of research I found why I was getting this error. Hope this helps.

I was using this jquery.ajaxQueue.js code on my website. This is a (really) old code to queue ajax requests ([link here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jquery-en/_eW89feVOM0)) and I had to change the line bellow:

```
$.ajax = function(settings) {
```

to:

```
$.ajax = function(url, settings) {
```

Now it's working fine.

Basically you should look for other jQuery plugins that mess with default jQuery .ajax() function.